# Where to put a cross domain policy file?

Tags: actionscript-3, policy

If I have my .swf files on "SERVER A" and they need to access my video files on "FMS SERVER B", on which server to I need to put a cross-domain policy file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the file on Server B and in the file allow access from server A

Answer (score 1):

It will need to go on server B.

If it were server A - the "client" side - you could write a cross domain file any time you liked, which would defeat the purpose.